# TextInputLayout counter hides when keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-edittext, counter, android-textinputlayout

I used TextInputLayout for my EditText and showing counter

But when the keyboard appear the counter is obscure by the keyboard.

```
android:windowSoftInput:"adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

didn't work for me. Here is the XML layout content

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">]

    <TextInputLayout
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterMaxLength="300"
        app:counterEnabled="true">

        <EditText 
          android:id="@+id/commentEdit"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColorHint="@color/blacktransperent"/>
 </TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Add screen shot, which can make better explanation.

Comment: Not a duplicate as the problem here is **not a hidden EditText but TextInputLayout's counter** which is under TextInputLayout's EditText.

Comment: Do you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` - add this in your `manifest` activity, in which activity you required

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have already added that line in my activity in manifest file.